# org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'Size.userForm.username' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to display error messages to the user when he registers on website. I am using spring, spring validation, spring security and mysql database. I am new to spring, and I can't figure this out.

Here is my html file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Create an account</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userForm" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create your account</h2>
        <spring:bind path="username">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="text" path="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                            autofocus="true"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="username"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="password">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <spring:bind path="passwordConfirm">
            <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                <form:input type="password" path="passwordConfirm" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
                <form:errors path="passwordConfirm"></form:errors>
            </div>
        </spring:bind>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form:form>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My dispatcher-servlet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.shop"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
     p:basename="WEB-INF/messages" />
</beans>
```

My UserValidation file:

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return User.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "NotEmpty");

        if (user.getUsername().length() < 6 || user.getUsername().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Size.userForm.username");
        }

        if (userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Duplicate.userForm.username");
        }

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "NotEmpty");
        if (user.getPassword().length() < 8 || user.getPassword().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "Size.userForm.password");
        }

        if (!user.getPasswordConfirm().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            errors.rejectValue("passwordConfirm", "Diff.userForm.passwordConfirm");
        }
    }
}
```

My file with the messages is in WEB-INF in messages folder, it is called validation.properties and look like this:

```
NotEmpty=This field is required.
Size.userForm.username=Please use between 6 and 32 characters.
Duplicate.userForm.username=Someone already has that username.
Size.userForm.password=Try one with at least 8 characters.
Diff.userForm.passwordConfirm=These passwords don't match.
```

I don't understand why cant it find the messages. This is the error that I am getting:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'Size.userForm.username' for locale 'en_US'.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think your default locale is `en_US` and not `en`. Adding `validation_en_US.properties` with same messages will fix the issue

Comment: I did what you said, and I get the same error:

org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'Size.userForm.username' for locale 'en_US'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the resource file naming convention like your file name should be

"messages_en_us.properties"

```
<bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
<property name="basename"> 
    <value>classpath*:messages</value> 
</property>
```

Since all your properties files are in classpath of java you need to define the path with prefix classpath*: otherwise it will look into the web directory of your application